# What String format is acceptable to append to this JSON output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net

I have an existing "blackbox" web service.  I need to append a session ID to the end of that output so that Javascript and similar clients can resume the stateful session.

Given the output below, what is the correct syntax to append or prepend an arbitrary GUID, so that it can be properly deserialized as valid JSON?

**Note**  This data below is perfect. If I can somehow add a "removable" bit of information, using JSON.NET the string GUID, that would be ideal.

Output from REST call

> "{\"sa\":[\"BHDQ9TLPeaeVuSSgXv9bsOIVFUWbOpivMKhGki7YPLzIXEyHuxRAZhDgts2sEcBQpLBuKJZCtcmSlzWZ9iK0AAA=\",\"BAhyo7T0Wq1WBLXnyN4vo1L94rWLhCCv4DqROi+p9XHO6UeS0Gw6xh1JAKOtXBU2fA432LkNqng8cUt1eAX0bqs=\",\"BGFmyTreWY5pICAcf3itoqbfhs5brOmIDLNF3V7p7slPYdCSVhwWUT5mHD6Lb5kNi\/Qy9tracNUtVgvo3f51FrI=\",\"BMV7RIwoz+LdFgD2fq7UZ7E88KFq\/03381NDYFIKYgUKxEzuXoj6hZfSB0slX5fdaL44Lf6i\/UjDzPQt2XUG8NE=\",\"BL8BnU5WvFn7vIlKi14dWsqykNf1\/nmE55YXFGwLx9Qu3VvDblULt\/U8CXPI1vD8+wMXCRnkunXqxlsFqgghf8w=\"],\"sb\":[\"BInTtgTAn\/zkmrkporhV5DvPZRq5YWm8e\/m02oq55UfY3RxIhOplJgwLjgKMHKYDthYEBcqNNNuVbbWnbtKVAqA=\",\"BJbh5y95wHGjmAPDFNqgewnBxtqVke0sloDD2S3IdrWZ95JfP77rtXZ4lTG8g9PuTLJbl4exZUnM16260WxJ9wU=\",\"BKevE9i2J8CicXHX3elCoQPEpTOmJyGOlBskIbFMFGQFhJ5TD7N1221rhhH9HY6DsfRojmefozsQYzo7Pokp+Hg=\",\"BJbVTRyh8WwCxfR7jRXnran4td7k5+vEfM+HWxeAibneSjdMRQ1Fg6QxKLu+Zu1aPdXqD8M29kABOTAiYopVuQE=\",\"BFv3alDqjo7ckdB2vuxJ15Gur1xsgATjLe9drt\/XU9AkbN+AELCv+mF1Xy8+83L2A1p8aGxF4b7dsrMed27u1j4=\"],\"sz\":\"BF1IiqMz0KmT4gZN6euJquWFt2UmVjyOEdaX0jH8uQMAPG8DBoyneT2PJ9NQTE2xBOP9TtAb1d2O+iCojFqzkvI=\"}"

The output above comes from Chrome. I'm not sure if Chrome adds additional quotes, etc but when I debug System.String on the server, I see the same thing being sent to the WCF service.

The end-usage for this will be a Chrome and Firefox plug in

Comment: Can you print it in console of the browser?

Comment: @Tom - Never interacted that way with JS.  I'm just browsing using GET to a service.  What do I do?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to use something like `JSON.parse()` on it, then edit the objects as needed and then use `JSON.stringify()` to get it back.

Comment: I just checked the server using a remote debugger, right before it's sent to the client.  The output is identical, so I don't think there is any need to use the console for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if I am correctly understanding:

You get JSON from a `blackbox` service. It contains some properties and values. You want to add a new property with some GUID and send it to browser.

If this is correct, try following:

```
var json=<WHAT YOU GET FROM SERVICE>;
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
obj.sid="this is the new session id"; //ADD NEW PROPERTY


var j=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); //GET BACK JSON STRING WITH NEW PROPERTY
```

Of if you just want to add session id on client side (inside your plugin) the utilize `JSON2` javascript library and use following code (as also suggested by Josh in comments):

```
var o = JSON.parse(<REST OUTPUT>);
o.sid = <YOUR SESSION ID>;
```

To convert back to `JSON` string.

```
var jsn = JSON.stringify(o);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to DeserializeObject?  The other answer just creates a new object.  Would that other way double-encode the data?

Comment: @makerofthings7 You are correct. In my answer I assume that `foo` is the deserialized response, else you would encode the JSON data as a string.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because if I'm going to have the choice between parsing twice on the client, or once on each the client and the server, I choose the latter.  (mobile devices are my target)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to modify that particular response without breaking existing clients. If you *can* break existing clients, or if you are working with clients that you control, you could wrap the object in another object, setting two keys: `GUID` and `data`. For example:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    data = foo,
    GUID = bar,
});
```

Where `bar` is the GUID that you want to use, and `foo` is one of two things:

1. The JSON string from the response. This will result in the final object looking like so:

   ```
   {
       data: "{\"sa\":[\"BHDQ9TLPeaeVuSSgXv9bsOIVFUWbOpivMKhGki7YPLzIXEyHuxRAZhDgts2sEcBQpLBuKJZCtcmSlzWZ9iK0AAA=\",\"BAhyo7T0Wq1WBLXnyN4vo1L94rWLhCCv4DqROi+p9XHO6UeS0Gw6xh1JAKOtXBU2fA432LkNqng8cUt1eAX0bqs=\",\"BGFmyTreWY5pICAcf3itoqbfhs5brOmIDLNF3V7p7slPYdCSVhwWUT5mHD6Lb5kNi\/Qy9tracNUtVgvo3f51FrI=\",\"BMV7RIwoz+LdFgD2fq7UZ7E88KFq\/03381NDYFIKYgUKxEzuXoj6hZfSB0slX5fdaL44Lf6i\/UjDzPQt2XUG8NE=\",\"BL8BnU5WvFn7vIlKi14dWsqykNf1\/nmE55YXFGwLx9Qu3VvDblULt\/U8CXPI1vD8+wMXCRnkunXqxlsFqgghf8w=\"],\"sb\":[\"BInTtgTAn\/zkmrkporhV5DvPZRq5YWm8e\/m02oq55UfY3RxIhOplJgwLjgKMHKYDthYEBcqNNNuVbbWnbtKVAqA=\",\"BJbh5y95wHGjmAPDFNqgewnBxtqVke0sloDD2S3IdrWZ95JfP77rtXZ4lTG8g9PuTLJbl4exZUnM16260WxJ9wU=\",\"BKevE9i2J8CicXHX3elCoQPEpTOmJyGOlBskIbFMFGQFhJ5TD7N1221rhhH9HY6DsfRojmefozsQYzo7Pokp+Hg=\",\"BJbVTRyh8WwCxfR7jRXnran4td7k5+vEfM+HWxeAibneSjdMRQ1Fg6QxKLu+Zu1aPdXqD8M29kABOTAiYopVuQE=\",\"BFv3alDqjo7ckdB2vuxJ15Gur1xsgATjLe9drt\/XU9AkbN+AELCv+mF1Xy8+83L2A1p8aGxF4b7dsrMed27u1j4=\"],\"sz\":\"BF1IiqMz0KmT4gZN6euJquWFt2UmVjyOEdaX0jH8uQMAPG8DBoyneT2PJ9NQTE2xBOP9TtAb1d2O+iCojFqzkvI=\"}",
       guid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   }
   ```

   And you would get at the data through two calls to `JSON.parse` (or the equivalent).
2. The deserialized object from the JSON response. This will result in the final object looking like so (most data removed for brevity sake):

   ```
   {
       data: {
           sa: [],
           sb: [],
           sz: ""
       },
       guid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   }
   ```

   And you would access `data` through `response.data`.

#### Why any modification can break existing clients

Where the current response is an object, there are only a few ways to modify it:

1. Injecting a key into the object. This assumes that no client uses `Object.keys()` or in any way iterates the key set (e.g. `for (k in obj)`). While this *may* be true, this is an assumption.
2. Adding another object to the end: `}, {`. Doing so would require that the response be transformed into an array:

   ```
   [{}, {}]
   ```

   This would break any client that is assumes the response is an object.
3. Wrapping the current response in a surrounding object (as proposed above). This as well breaks any clients that assumes a certain structure for the response.

   ```
   {data:{}, guid: ""}
   ```

Comment: Why would adding a key/value pair break clients?

Comment: Does this encode `foo` as a string? or will the JSON get double escaped?